# How to run commands as an Administrator in context menu right click?

Tags: windows, context-menu

How to run commands as an Administrator in context menu right click?
This code works properly, but runs as a normal user :-(
Can anyone advise how to fix it? Thank you.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A]
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B]
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group C]
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group C\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group C\shell\Command A]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group C\shell\Command A\command]
@="cmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group C\shell\Command B]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group C\shell\Command B\command]
@="cmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group D]
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group D\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group D\shell\Command C]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group D\shell\Command C\command]
@="cmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group D\shell\Command D]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Group A\shell\Group B\shell\Group D\shell\Command D\command]
@="cmd"
```

Comment: Maybe you can find something helpful here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/andrew_richards/enhancing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shift-right-click-context-menu-experience

Comment: It only works in the first level :( Another idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is working properly

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\shell\runas]
@="Test"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe"
```

This doesn't work, why?

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\shell\Demo]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\shell\Demo\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\shell\Demo\shell\runas]
@="Test"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\shell\Demo\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe"
```